# Word that means "two-person photo"?

Tags: single-word-requests, phrase-requests

Is there a word for that?

Example sentence:

> He didn't want to take a selfie. He wanted a _.

Comment: The "two-person" refers to the person who is taking the photo with a friend, or a photo of two people. It's a good to clarify this ambiguous point.

Comment: If you look at how often "a selfie *with*" is used, I don't think you'll find a suitable word. You might get one with the meaning, but it wouldn't fit the same register.

Comment: Are you looking for a [retronym](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Retronym) for what we used to just call *photo(graph)s*? That is, do you want a term for a photo where the subject and photographer are different people, rather than one where the subject pointed the camera at him- or herself?

Comment: Have a look at the [Group Selfies](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Selfie#Group_selfies) section of the *selfie* wikipedia article.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In film theory, such framing is called a two-shot. I believe the same term is used in photography. I don't know of a less formal term.

Urban dictionary suggests "usie"/"ussie" or "groupie". "Friendsie" seems like it would fit, but these all sound stupid to me. You could probably just make something up.

Comment: _Ussie_ could work. _Groupie_ is a bit unfortunate, since it’s something else (ironically a single person). _Friendsie_ just sounds like a one-piece jumpsuit for multiple people.